# Find out alpha such that f is continous

Tags: limits, continuity

Find out alpha such that f is continous in point 1:
$$ f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R, f(x) = \begin{cases}
    \frac{\ln(1 + \ln(2-x))}{(x-1)^\alpha},x \not= 1 \\
     -1, x = 1.
\end{cases}
$$
Basically, I should find out y = lim as x->1, then y = -1 and find alpha.
I didn't learn yet about derivatives, so the only way I know to solve such limits with undeterminate form is using remarcable limits. I don't know how to tackle this limit.

Comment: You may know that $$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\ln (1+z)}{z} = 1.$$ That is the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Taylor series approach as

> $$ \ln(1+\ln(2-x))= -(x-1)+O ( ( x-1 ) ^{2} ) \implies \ln(1+\ln(2-x))\sim -(x-1). $$

which gives

> $$\frac{\ln(1+\ln(2-x))}{(x-1)^\alpha} \sim_{x\sim 1} \frac{-(x-1)}{(x-1)^\alpha}=\dots\,.  $$